# How to merge in a reducer two objects in one merging also a subfiled which is an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet which uses a `reduce` and I cannot use another kind of loops, I have as a requirement to solve this by a `reduce` or a way which does not include a loop as `for` or `forEach`

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-playground-forked-y83ok2?file=/src/index.js)

As you will see I have an array of objects and inside it, I have 2 objects with the same `studyId`.

What I need is to merge the objects with the same `studyId` and the subfield `siteIds` in one array to have the following result

```
{ studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Paris", "Bon", "PLACEHOLDER", "Amsterdam", "Bruxelles" ] }
```

The `siteIds` also need to be unique I cannot have repeated the same `siteId` in the array

In the snippet, I tried with the reducer as I have that as a requirement but cannot figure out how to achieve the result I need.

Including the full desired output as was confusing a super comments

```
[
   // Here the merged with the same StudyId
  { studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Paris", "Bon", "PLACEHOLDER", "Amsterdam", "Bruxelles", "Paris"] },
  {
    studyId: "ANNO6",
    siteIds: ["Rome", "Torino", "PLACEHOLDER", "Milano"]
  },
  { studyId: "ANNO7", siteIds: undefined },
  { studyId: "ANNO8", siteIds: undefined }
];
```

as per `undefined` the requirement is similar to having something like this

```
siteIds: isEmpty(siteIds) ? undefined : uniq(siteIds),
```

When no `siteIds` we have undefined as per the above example

Comment: `ANNO7` shouldn't appear in the resultant array?

Comment: I have to include all results at the moment as requirement

Comment: Could you also add the expected output for the input `siteIds`

Comment: it is already in the question the result I need when we have the same studyId we have siteIds merged in one array without duplicates  
`siteIds: ["Paris", "Bon", "PLACEHOLDER", "Amsterdam", "Bruxelles" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the data by `studyId` using `reduce` and use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicate `siteIds`.

```js
const siteIds = [
  { studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Paris", "Bon", "PLACEHOLDER"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Amsterdam", "Bruxelles", "PLACEHOLDER", "Paris"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO6", siteIds: ["Rome", "Torino", "PLACEHOLDER", "Milano"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO7", siteIds: undefined },
  { studyId: "ANNO8", siteIds: undefined },
];

const result = Object.values(
  siteIds.reduce((r, o) => {
    if (!r[o.studyId]) {
      r[o.studyId] = { ...o, siteIds: undefined };
    }
    if (o.siteIds) {
      (r[o.studyId].siteIds ??= []).push(...o.siteIds);
      r[o.studyId].siteIds = [...new Set(r[o.studyId].siteIds)];
    }
    return r;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

If you want to avoid creating sets in every iteration, then refer to the snippet below:

```js
const siteIds = [
  { studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Paris", "Bon", "PLACEHOLDER"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO5", siteIds: ["Amsterdam", "Bruxelles", "PLACEHOLDER", "Paris"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO6", siteIds: ["Rome", "Torino", "PLACEHOLDER", "Milano"] },
  { studyId: "ANNO7", siteIds: undefined },
  { studyId: "ANNO8", siteIds: undefined },
];


const result = Object.values(
  siteIds.reduce((r, o) => {
    if (!r[o.studyId]) {
      r[o.studyId] = { ...o, siteIds: undefined };
    }
    if (o.siteIds) {
      (r[o.studyId].siteIds ??= []).push(...o.siteIds);
    }
    return r;
  }, {})
).map((o) => ({
  ...o,
  ...(o.siteIds && { siteIds: [...new Set(o.siteIds)] }),
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: cool but running your snippet I see only one result I should have a new array of results per every `StudyId`I see only `ANNO5`

Comment: The desired result in your question also just contained `ANN05`, so I've only kept that. How do you want your result to look please add that in the question.

Comment: @Jakub For `ANN07` you want `siteIds` to be `undefined` or an empty array `[]`?

Comment: Yes maybe I was not precise that was the output for the merging of 2 studyId not the full output I'll include the full result now

Comment: Yes that perfect :)